# How to check if file locked/open via Graph API/SDK

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to delete a file in a document library (personal OneDrive) via the Graph SDK (using c#)

```
await graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[driveItemId].Request().DeleteAsync();
```

It works. But if the file is open it'll throw this error:

```
423 : Locked
....
"error": {
    "code": "resourceLocked",
    "message": "The resource you are attempting to access is locked",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "d1bfa1f2-cXXXXX",
      "date": "2020-05-02T04:05:23"
    }
```

Is there any possibility **to check** if file is locked/open via Graph API/SDK?)

My current solution is:
i make this call

```
await graphClient.Drives["{driveid}"].Items["{driveItemid}"].Checkout().Request().PostAsync();
```

In case if file is open i ge t the same 423 error response. Then i ask user to make it close and repeat.
In case if i get 204 No content response  i make call to delete  driveItem.

But i do not think it is an elegant problem solving. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The solution that we found was making and passing a HeaderOption that bypasses the shared lock, then adding it into the request. This bypasses the locked file 423 error response. And allows the graphServiceClient to delete the file regardless of whether it is open or not.

```
List<Microsoft.Graph.Option> reqOptions = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Option>
    {
        new Microsoft.Graph.HeaderOption("Prefer", "bypass-shared-lock")
    };

await graphServiceClient.Groups[groupId].Drive.Items[driveItem.Id].Request(reqOptions).DeleteAsync();
```